# Too many open files - socket(2) with net/http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets

I have a problem with http requests with net/http...

I writing a ruby script that interacts with the dailymotion api.
This script will upload a video "test.flv".
Basically it consists of four requests.

It works perfectly until step "#Create the video object".
The following error is raised on the last
"response = http.request(req)" command ->

Errno::EMFILE: Too many open files - socket(2)

Here is the code, thx for any advice...

```
require 'net/http'
require 'curb'
require 'json'


# Authenticate the user
url = URI.parse( 'https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/token' )
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.set_form_data({ 'grant_type' => 'password',
           'client_id' => 'my_client_id',
           'client_secret' => 'my_client_secret',
           'username' => 'myusername',
           'password' => 'mypassword'
         })
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response = http.request(req)

access_token = JSON.parse( response.body )['access_token']
access_url = 'https://api.dailymotion.com/file/upload?access_token=' + access_token



# Get an upload URL
url = URI.parse( access_url )
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new( url.request_uri )
http = Net::HTTP.new( url.host, url.port )
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response = http.request( req )

upload_url = JSON.parse( response.body )['upload_url']
progress_url = JSON.parse( response.body )['progress_url']


# Post the video
fields_hash = {}

post_data = fields_hash.map { |k, v| Curl::PostField.content(k, v.to_s) }
post_data << Curl::PostField.file('file', 'C:/test.flv')

c = Curl::Easy.new(upload_url)
c.multipart_form_post = true
c.http_post(post_data)

file_url = JSON.parse( c.body_str )['url']


# Create the video object
url = URI.parse( 'https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos' )
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.set_form_data({ 'url' => file_url,
                'access_token' => access_token
         })
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response = http.request(req)

puts response.body
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling finish

```
http.finish
```

after the response = http.request( req ).

Comment: Tried it on after the last response = http.request( req ) where the error raises, but still the error is raised (propably it can't call finish because the error is raised before)
Also tried it on after the response = http.request( req ) earlier in my script, but this always gives me this Error...
IOError: HTTP session not yet started

Comment: It might be that the session is started when reading the body.  Try the finish call right after the JSON.parse( response.body ) line, both for access_token = ... and progress_url = ...

Comment: thx for answering...
Put the finish call after reading the body but I'm still getting the IOError